# How to upload files from form to server and store in a new folder

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, file-io

I'm having trouble trying to upload files from a form and create a new folder and store those forms.

My code is:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['uploadfiles']['name']); $i++) {
    $temp = explode(".", strtolower($_FILES['uploadfiles']["name"][$i]));
    $extension = end($temp);
    //var_dump($extension);
    if ((($_FILES['uploadfiles']["type"][$i] == "image/pdf")
        || ($_FILES['uploadfiles']["type"][$i] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES['uploadfiles']["type"][$i] == "image/jpg")
        || ($_FILES['uploadfiles']["type"][$i] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES['uploadfiles']["type"][$i] == "image/png")
        || ($_FILES['uploadfiles']["type"][$i] == "image/x-png"))
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExtensions)) {
          if ($_FILES['uploadfiles']["error"][$i] > 0) {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES['uploadfiles']["error"][$i] . "<br>";
          } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfiles']["tmp_name"][$i],
               $folder_destination . $_FILES['uploadfiles']["name"][$i]);
          }
    }
  }
```

I would like to create a folder or check if the folder exists and write the files submitted via the form to that folder.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Do you get something in the $_FILES variable?

Comment: @user1680977 I get a warning `Warning: move_uploaded_file(135/1/24-09-2014/Capture.PNG): failed to open stream: `

Comment: You can use `is_dir()` and `mkdir()` to check if folder exists and create it.

Comment: either you have not permission to file write in that folder or you dont have created a folder folder dont exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the for() loop, you should do:

```
if (!is_dir($folder_destination)) { mkdir($folder_destination,0777); }
```

This will create the folder with global write permissions in case if it's not yet present.

Answer (score 1):

You can create folder like that but make sure you have write permission

```
if (!file_exists($folder_destination)) {
    mkdir($folder_destination, 0777, true); 
}
```

copy your file to there like that

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfiles']["tmp_name"][$i], $folder_destination . $_FILES['uploadfiles']["name"][$i]);
```

Comment: wut? if file doesn't exist create a directory? Shouldn't this be `!is_dir($folder_destination)` ? (honest question, not bashing.)

Comment: have you check this function?

Comment: This is why stack overflow is interesting, everyday we see somthing new. :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the warning you're getting, I would guess that the problem is that you don't have a permission to write to the folder or the folder doesn't exist.

You can check [chmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) function to change the rights or do it manually on the server.